# ACF: replace comma with another sign

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I am using ACF.

I am using this function to display numbers in number fields in this way 1,000.00

```
// Return ACF Number Fields Formatted with Commas on the Frontend
add_filter('acf/format_value/type=number', 'acf_number_comma_decimal', 20, 3);

// Without Decimal
function acf_number_comma($value, $post_id, $field) {
$value = number_format(floatval($value));
return $value;
}
// With Decimal
function acf_number_comma_decimal($value, $post_id, $field) {
$value = number_format(floatval($value), 2);
return $value;
}
```

I would like to replace the ” , ” with this ” ‘ ” so the value will be displayed in this way: 1’000.00.

How can i achieve that?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation of [`number_format()`](https://www.php.net/number_format)? It provides options for thousands separator.

Comment: @kero many thanks for yor answer. How do I add this to Wordpress?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You already "added it to WordPress" with the code you posted above. All that is necessary is to change the arguments of one of the functions in use.

Comment: @kero yeah I added the previous code in my functions.php file following a tutorial.

What do you mean with "change the arguments of one of the functions in use"?

Sorry I am not an expert in PHP

Answer (score 0):

Modify the following line in your function:

```
$value = number_format(floatval($value), 2);
```

To include another two arguments from the number_format() function - namely the decimal separator (set to a dot) and the thousands separator (set to an apostrophe)

```
$value = number_format(floatval($value), 2, ".", "'");
```

So in total this line says: format the number (after floating it to an integer) to two decimal places using a dot to separate decimals and an apostrophe to separate the thousands.

Online demo: https://shorturl.at/twFWX